# Rotating logstash logs holding onto file handle. Can I force it to write to a new log?

Tags: elasticsearch, redis, logstash

So I have been experimenting with rotating the logs in logstash. I created a script to rotate the logs because logrotate is undesirable in my environment. With that said it rotates the logs correctly but logstash still writes to the old file even after renaming and moving the file.

I am hesitant to delete said file at the risk of causing the service to crash. A few other posts indicated that it would let go of the file handle after a few hours but its been days with multiple renames and it still writes to the same file.

The config options offer a max file size but according to the documentation it isnt supported yet. Is there a way to force logstash to write to the new log file without restarting the service?

Comment: I stood up a duplicate environment to test in. Looks like the service stops working even though the pid hangs around if you delete the active log file. I added a service restart to my script and everything seems to work. I would prefer a less volatile way to accomplish this so if anyone has any suggestions I am open to them.